# James said if he wasn't a start for the competition that he be left out completely

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

> **James said if he** wasn't a start for the competition that he be left
>   out completely.
>
> said if he

is it (conditional in indirect speech) and mean about present?

Comment: The usage "to be a start" is "unusual" (domain-specific?) phrasing. What James means is if they don't include him among the ***first*** team members taking to the field, he doesn't want to play at all. That would be a ***hypothetical*** situation, reflected by use of the ***subjunctive*** ("that he **be...**").

Comment: (Personally, I think the syntax of your example is all over the place. It might be something some native speakers would accept, but imho it's not a well-formed utterance.)